# DROP IDENTITY FROM COLUMN ORACLE 19C

Tags: sql, oracle, database-administration, oracle19c

Is there any way to drop identity specification from a column in Oracle db19c?
Some sort of script on sys tables?

Comment: "Some sort of script on sys tables?" - you should *never* update or modify SYS tables - messing around with the SYS schema is likely to destroy your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as you said it - `drop identity`.

```
SQL> create table test
  2    (id number generated always as identity);

Table created.

SQL> alter table test modify id drop identity;

Table altered.

SQL>
```

[Oracle 19c ALTER TABLE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/ALTER-TABLE.html#GUID-552E7373-BF93-477D-9DA3-B2C9386F2877) (search for "drop identity").